# Z-index'ы не слушаются. Как решить проблему?

Tags: css

[Код вот тут:](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct64c/1/)

Мне нужно чтобы внизу стоял блок - черный, а сверху - красный. Приписываю им z-index 1 и 2, соответственно, но не работает!

Иногда бывает что индексы не слушаются вот так. В чем проблема?

Comment: немного ознакомился с вашим кодом. и думаю, что решение задачи возможно без использования z-index'ов.

Опишите или примерно нарисуйте, чего вы хотите?

Comment: хочу при наведении курсора красный блок поднялся, тем самым показывая стоящий под ним черный блок. @silksOfTheSoul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй поставить position: absolute; или :fixed; для двух блоков.

---

у меня не получилось расшарить код с этого сервиса, поэтому кидаю сюда.

```
    #row1, #row2 {
    height: 320px;
    width: 960px;

    outline: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;

    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.grid1, .grid2, .grid3 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;

    background: #00f0ca;
    padding:4px;
}

.block {
    height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;

    position: absolute;
}

.grid_cover {
    height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #ccc;

    top:24px;
    left:4px;

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

отступы и цвет настроил для своего удобства, вы настройте так как вам нужно(соответственно и абсолютное позиционирование поправте).

Comment: значит вся проблема была в типе позиционирования? =/ Спасибо!

Comment: ... или как нибудь так)

.block {
 height: 320px;
 width: 320px;
 outline: 1px solid black;
 background-color: #ff0000;
 z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    
    position: absolute;
}
.grid1:hover .block, .grid2:hover .block, .grid3:hover .block{
    z-index: 1;
}